# ¿Cómo setear valores en una propiedad que es un array y es del tipo de una clase?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde debo serializar una clase en un Json, en esta clase existe una propiedad que es un arreglo y el tipo es de una clase, 
fíjense esta es la propiedad declarada como arreglo

```
private FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle[] detalleServicioField;
```

esta es la clase que define el tipo de dicha propiedad

```
public partial class FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle {

    private string numeroLineaField;

    private CodigoType[] codigoField;

    private decimal cantidadField;

    private UnidadMedidaType unidadMedidaField;

    private string unidadMedidaComercialField;

    private string detalleField;

    private decimal precioUnitarioField;

    private decimal montoTotalField;

    private decimal montoDescuentoField;

    private bool montoDescuentoFieldSpecified;

    private string naturalezaDescuentoField;

    private decimal subTotalField;

    private ImpuestoType[] impuestoField;

    private decimal montoTotalLineaField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="positiveInteger")]
    public string NumeroLinea {
        get {
            return this.numeroLineaField;
        }
        set {
            this.numeroLineaField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Codigo")]
    public CodigoType[] Codigo {
        get {
            return this.codigoField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Cantidad {
        get {
            return this.cantidadField;
        }
        set {
            this.cantidadField = value;
        }
    }

    public UnidadMedidaType UnidadMedida {
        get {
            return this.unidadMedidaField;
        }
        set {
            this.unidadMedidaField = value;
        }
    }

    public string UnidadMedidaComercial {
        get {
            return this.unidadMedidaComercialField;
        }
        set {
            this.unidadMedidaComercialField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Detalle {
        get {
            return this.detalleField;
        }
        set {
            this.detalleField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal PrecioUnitario {
        get {
            return this.precioUnitarioField;
        }
        set {
            this.precioUnitarioField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal MontoTotal {
        get {
            return this.montoTotalField;
        }
        set {
            this.montoTotalField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal MontoDescuento {
        get {
            return this.montoDescuentoField;
        }
        set {
            this.montoDescuentoField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MontoDescuentoSpecified {
        get {
            return this.montoDescuentoFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.montoDescuentoFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public string NaturalezaDescuento {
        get {
            return this.naturalezaDescuentoField;
        }
        set {
            this.naturalezaDescuentoField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal SubTotal {
        get {
            return this.subTotalField;
        }
        set {
            this.subTotalField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Impuesto")]
    public ImpuestoType[] Impuesto {
        get {
            return this.impuestoField;
        }
        set {
            this.impuestoField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal MontoTotalLinea {
        get {
            return this.montoTotalLineaField;
        }
        set {
            this.montoTotalLineaField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy seteando valores para otras propiedades de la forma siguiente, nesecito seguir este estilo para lo que explico anteriormente...

```
Receptor = new ReceptorType
                {
                    Nombre = "",
                    Identificacion = new IdentificacionType
                    {
                        Numero = "2312",
                        Tipo = (IdentificacionTypeTipo)Enum.Parse(typeof(IdentificacionTypeTipo), "")
                    },
                    IdentificacionExtranjero = "A12ERS",
                    NombreComercial = "HARINA",
                    Ubicacion = new UbicacionType
                    {
                        Provincia = "Carabobo",
                        Canton = "S/N",
                        Distrito = "MiguelPeña",
                        Barrio = "Don Bosco",
                        OtrasSenas = "S/N"
                    },
                    Telefono = new TelefonoType
                    {
                        NumTelefono = "34234",
                        CodigoPais = "058"
                    },
                    Fax = new TelefonoType
                    {
                        NumTelefono = "555000",
                        CodigoPais = "058"
                    },
                    CorreoElectronico = "dhas"
                }
```

ya que cuando escribo esto  me marca un error donde dice : SE ESPERABA UN INICIALIZADOR DE LA MATRIZ CON LONGITUD 14

```
 DetalleServicio = new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle[14]
                {

                }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Puedes explicar exactamente que problema tienes? Lo único que veo es una clase extensa y la inicialización de otra que no tiene nada que ver con la primera...

Comment: No queda claro lo que preguntas

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es bastante claro. Si quieres inicializar un array de longitud 14 inline, debes crear 14 instancias de la clase del array. Vamos con un ejemplo por si no ha quedado claro:

```
var DetalleServicio = new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle[2] 
                  { new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle { Cantidad=1... }, 
                    new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle { Cantidad=1...} };
```

Como ves en este ejemplo, al crear el array de longitud 2, debo crear 2 instancias de la clase e inicializarlas.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh...